# Strong parameters with polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a polymorphic comment system per railscasts episode 154. I can't seem to get the strong parameters to accept the right field. In the POST action the parameters come through like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/yVWatJSRY1AmAqgbS4Z9S8kIlfQAKBbUeHc/5coxeM=",
 "comment"=>{"content"=>"Hello"},
 "commit"=>"Create Comment",
 "user_id"=>"1"}
```

And My MVC I will post below. Does anyone know the correct way to use strong parameters in this case?

Model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :votes
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable   
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_commentable

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params.require(:comment [:content]))
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to [@commentable, :comments], notice: "Comment created."
    else
        render :new
    end
end


  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end
end
```

View

```
<h1>New Comment</h1>


<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
<div class="error_messages">

    <h2>Please correct the following errors.</h2>
    <ul><% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %>
            <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field" >
<%= f.text_area :content, rows: 8 %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

It should't be any different then any other controller in terms of strong params.

does

```
 @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:content))
```

not work?